# Shell script: Replace matching text with output of program

Tags: perl, shell, command-line

I want to replace specific strings in a text stream with the output of a program run on those strings.  For example, replace any occurrence of "#filename#" with the output of `identify filename`

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you need to change the replacement string dynamically or is the output of `identify filename` static (for that stream)?

Comment: I want to change the output dynamically: I can't predict what filenames I will get until I see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming '`identify filename`' is itself a command, then I think you'll need to use Perl for this.  In the best Perl inscrutable style:

```
while (<>)
{
     s/#(\w+)#/my $x = qx%identify $1%; chomp $x; $x/e;
     print;
}
```

This reads a line of input ('`<>`') into the implicit variable '`$_`'; the next line applies a substitute operation to the implicit variable - more details in a moment - and then the '`print`' prints the implicit variable.

As to the substitute operation '`s///`', the first part looks for a hash '#', a series of one or more 'word' characters - alphanumerics or underscore - and another hash, making the identified file name available as '`$1`'.  The second part is the replacement string.  After the third slash is the modifier '`e`' which means 'execute the replacement as bit of Perl'.  And the relevant bit of Perl is:

```
my $x = qx%identify $1%; chomp $x; $x
```

The first part executes the command '`identify filename`' if the string between the hash marks is 'filename', saving the output, newline and all, in local variable $x.  The '`chomp`' operation removes the newline; the final '`$x`' yields a value - the string that was output by the 'identify' command.  (Somewhat to my surprise, Perl does not allow a simpler looking: `s/#(\w+)#/chomp qx%identify $1%/e`; the error was '``` Can't modify quoted execution (``, qx) in chomp at xx.pl line 3, near "qx%identify $1%)" ```'.)

Consider the 'identify' command:

```
echo "identified file $1 as $PWD/$1"
```

Now consider the input line:

```
abc#def#ghi
```

The output is:

```
abcidentified file def as /Users/jleffler/tmp/soq/defghi
```

(where `/Users/jleffler/tmp/soq` happened to be my current directory while running the command).

Rather less inscrutably:

```
while (my $line = <>)
{
    if ($line =~ m/#(\w+)#/)
    {
        my $identity = qx{identify $1};
        chomp $identity;
        $line =~ s/#\w+#/$identity/;
    }
    print $line;
}
```

Certainly not as compact, but the explanation is very similar.

Note that the initial edition is not the most compact form possible.  Consider this version:

```
perl -p -e 's/#(\w+)#/my $x = qx%identify $1%; chomp $x; $x/e'
```

The '-p' option places the script (the argument to '-e') in a read, execute, print loop (REPL).

That's one of the wonders of Perl - TMTOWTDI (pronounced 'tim-toady') - There's More Than One Way To Do It.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Let me add, though, that (\w+) is not the best match for filenames: it doesn't accept periods.

Comment: @nikitakit: undoubtedly correct - but that is where you know what rules you need to apply and I can't tell.  You can consider using a regex such as '`\w[\w/.]*\w`' to pick up file names that start and end with an alphanumeric but that can contain slashes and dots.  Or you can refine/extend the rule in numerous ways.  One very accepting regex is '`[^#]+`'; it accepts anything except hashes between the two hash marks.

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACEMENT=`identify filename`
sed "s/#filename#/$REPLACEMENT/g"
```

EDIT: See Dennis Williamson's comment.

Comment: You need to change the single quotes to double quotes for that to work. The `#` don't need to be escaped.